# view based vs windows based iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

REF: XCode

what is the differences between view based vs windows based iphone application?

Where are you going to use view based and windows based application?

Example? what does facebook use?

Comment: Facebook uses the three20 library. Google three20 and you'll find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regards to your question about the difference between `View-based` and `Window-based` templates, a `View` template gives you a `Window` template with a `UIView` already added and configured to display in the window, while the `Window` template gives you a blank slate with no default view set up.

Answer (score 0):

[About Windows, Views, and Controls](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503)

[Understanding iPhone Views, Windows and the View Hierarchy](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_iPhone_Views,_Windows_and_the_View_Hierarchy)

Usually only one window in UIWindow application. Apps can and ususally have multiple views, for example there are multiple views in a your typical iOS navigation application

Comment: I'm confused as to why is there two different templates, windows based and view based... why do we need windows based to begin with? you can create a view based and it does the same thing?

Comment: I noticed they took it out in XCode 4